# Makefile: missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?)

Tags: linux, makefile, debian

My generated makefile doesn't execute, instead it throws the following error:
`vbsp_linux32.mak:34: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.`

I've read like 30 pages, which all come to the same conclusion (spaces in front of commands) which I am not able to find/solve in this makefile:

http://pastebin.com/2cYd8Jhj

OS: Debian Jessie

Make version: 4.0

Comment: Show us vbsp_linux32.mk file. im bit confused here, is http://pastebin.com/2cYd8Jhj is only vbsp_linux32.mk file?

Comment: @SagarSakre The file on pastebin is only the vbsp_linux32.mak file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line *34* is a command.

```
call ..\..\vpc_scripts\valve_p4_edit.cmd ..\..\..\game\bin\$(TargetFileName) ..\..
```

According to [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Contents) (you can go over the whole page):

> Makefiles contain five kinds of things: explicit rules, implicit rules, variable definitions, directives, and comments. Rules, variables, and directives are described at length in later chapters.

In other words you can have commands in a *Makefile* but (most common case) in rules.

However this is only one of many errors the *Makefile* contains. Looking at it i see that it was translated from Windows:

- *backslashes* as path separators
- copy

  ```
  copy "$(TargetDir)"$(TargetFileName) ..\..\..\game\bin\$(TargetFileName)
  ```
- call

  ```
  call ..\..\vpc_scripts\valve_p4_edit.cmd ..\..\..\game\bin\$(TargetFileName) ..\..
  ```
- ERRORLEVEL

  ```
  if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BuildEventFailed
  ```
- and others

So there is some work to do til it will work on Linux.